# How do I remove the "Clear" button from input type="date" in Chrome?

Tags: html

How do I remove/hide this button:

[image]

I've tried many of the commonly proposed solutions including:

- Setting the `required` attribute
- Using `display:none` on `-webkit-clear-button`

None of these appear to work. Here's a simple example:

https://codepen.io/ilitirit/pen/gOKVGgp

It doesn't appear to work in Chrome or Edge.

Comment: Unfortunately, datapicker UI [differs a lot between browsers](). While you can style the `input` field itself (i.e. how the date string is rendered inside the `input`), the popover panel with calendar UI is contained inside a [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) and cannot be styled. `-webkit-` pseudo-selectors on `input[type="date"]` only affects the input field itself (see [this](https://codepen.io/MuTLY/pen/VvJaMx)). For fully custom UI, you might need a third-party library.